# How to pass php directory files into javascript array?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, directory

I am trying to create an image slideshow from a directory on my local server. I'm using php to access the files using `readDir()`.  I them want to pass the variables into a javascript array to then access whatever feature I want with them. Right now I'm just trying to print them out to the screen, to make sure it works, but I'm not getting anything on the screen at all.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      var images = new Array();
<?php
$dp = opendir("img/slideshow");
while($currentFile !== false){
  if($currentFile != "." && $currentFile != ".."){
    $currentFile = readDir($dp);
    echo("images.push('{$currentFile}');");
  }
}
?>
      for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        document.write("<a href = '" + images[i] + "'>" + images[i] + "</a>");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seemed pretty logical to me. I start out with creating the javascript array, then in the php part, I open, and read the directory then echo out a line of code that pushes the current file into the javascript array.  Then it should print out each array item, but I'm getting a blank screen. ****Note: if I place the files into a php array and print it out, it works just fine but I can't access the array through javascript and put animations to it****

Comment: You have a stray < at the start of your echo that would cause a JS parse error. When you execute this do you get any errors from PHP or in the JS console?

Comment: You seem to have an extra `<` in the following line `echo("<images.push('{$currentFile}');");`.. You need to remove that.

Comment: I apologize, that's not in my actual code, I misprinted it when typing it here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

<?php
$dp = opendir("img/slideshow");
$arrayjs = array();
while($currentFile !== false){
  if($currentFile != "." && $currentFile != ".."){
    $currentFile = readDir($dp);
    $arrayjs[] = $currentFile;
  }
}
echo "var images = " . json_encode($arrayjs) . ";";
?>

      for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        document.write("<a href = '" + images[i] + "'>" + images[i] + "</a>");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir="img/slideshow";//set the working directory
$pics= scandir($dir) ;//Makes a array with all the items of the array
unset($pics[0],$pics[1]);//first and second ellement are the "."".." is nesecery to unset!
$string = '<script type ="text/javascript">var images =[ ';
foreach($pics as $key => $item) {
$string.='"'.$item.'",';
}
echo substr($string, 0, -1)."];</script>"; ?>
```